# Where do XCode 3 User Project Templates live?

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

I've installed a set of project templates for XCode 3.2.6. Where on disk can I find the templates and are they simple scripts I can edit? For instance I want to change the name of the template displayed in the "new project" window; also I was asked for some configuration settings during template installation and I would like to see/change those settings.

Is there a "template manager" in Xcode 3, or should I be directly editing files in some special dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're found in `/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/`. It's possible there's one other place they live, too, but I don't remember it off the top of my head.